# Apache Ignite integration with scala-spark using sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, ignite

I am trying to integrate ignite in scala code and run the application using sbt. I cannot use any IDE for this.

```
Scala version - 2.11.0
Spark version - 2.3.0
Ignite version - 2.8.0
Sbt version - 1.3.3
```

I have tried adding the basic library dependency in sbt.build,

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.ignite" %% "ignite-spark" % "2.8.0"
```

my complete sbt.build code is,

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.ignite" %% "ignite-spark" % "2.8.0"
```

but it is still not working, I am getting the following error:

```
$ sbt package
[info] Loading project definition from /home/testing/project
[info] Loading settings for project testing from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to testing (in build file:/home/testing/)
[info] Updating 
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.ignite:ignite-spark_2.11:2.8.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /root/.ivy2/local/org.apache.ignite/ignite-spark_2.11/2.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-spark_2.11/2.8.0/ignite-spark_2.11-2.8.0.pom
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:245)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$34(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:214)
[error]         at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:214)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:102)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:69)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:115)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:96)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:150)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:129)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$5(Defaults.scala:2946)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.ignite:ignite-spark_2.11:2.8.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /root/.ivy2/local/org.apache.ignite/ignite-spark_2.11/2.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-spark_2.11/2.8.0/ignite-spark_2.11-2.8.0.pom
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed May 28, 2020 6:24:04 AM
```

I am working on Ubuntu:latest docker image.
I am sure that spark and ignite are working as I am also running pyspark and it is working just fine. Please help me out, I think being a newbie I am doing some minor mistake which is becoming a major issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that he tries to pool "ignite_spark_2.11", not only "ignite_spark".

"not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-spark_2.11/2.8.0/ignite-spark_2.11-2.8.0.pom"

use

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.ignite" % "ignite-spark" % "2.8.0"
```

instead of

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.ignite" %% "ignite-spark" % "2.8.0"
```

%% -> get dependencies with scala version appended

% -> get dependencies without scala version appended

Comment: Thanks a lot, this downloaded the right packages and sbt package command worked.